# Autofoco em um input fazendo aparecer o teclado e primeira mauíscula

Tags: javascript, android, cordova-plugin

Estou usando o Cordova para desenvolver meu app usando HTML, CSS e JavaScript.
Quando utilizo o comando "Prompt" para o operador inserir um item em meu app, o Android traz a caixa de texto corretamente, porém não coloca o foco no input, obrigando o operador a tocar na tela para dar o foco no campo e trazer o teclado.

Tem como fazer isso automaticamente assim que abrir o prompt? Será que é alguma configuração no projeto do Cordova que faz isso?

Segue a função que uso para trazer o Prompt para o operador.

```
function NovoItem(iId){
   var sNome = '';
   var opc = 0;

   navigator.notification.prompt(
      'Item:',                               // Mensagem que aparece
      function(retorno){                     // Função de CallBack
         sNome = retorno.input1;
         opc = retorno.buttonIndex;

         if (opc == 1){
            InserirItem(iId, sNome);
         }
      },
      'Novo',                                // Título
      ['Ok', 'Cancelar'],                    // Botões disponíveis
      '');                                   // Texto padrão
}
```